# HTML5 Canvas drag coordinates bad

Tags: jquery, html

I need to create a Paint Like canvas with NODEJS. I successfully created. But, I have a problem with the coordinates. It works perfectly on Safari and Chrome (MAC OSX). But When I tested it with Firefox The 'X' and 'Y' coordinates move a little bit. like 50px in X and Y. I leave the code, any ideas?

```
$('canvas').live('drag dragstart dragend', function(e) {
      //Color
      var color = '#000000';

    var offset, type, x, y;
    type = e.handleObj.type;
    offset = $(this).offset();
    e.offsetX = e.layerX - offset.left;
    e.offsetY = e.layerY - offset.top;
    x = e.layerX;
    y = e.layerY;
    App.draw(x, y, type, color);
    App.socket.emit('drawClick', {
      x: x,
      y: y,
      type: type,
      color: color
    });

  });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I get the same results, firefox there seems to be no offset when drawing on the canvas. Perhaps a deeper look into jquery draw canvas script might show how things might differ between browsers.